# User - move group on Edit?

Tags: members, solspace-user

Is it possible to move the Member group on editing of the User profile?

We've set it up so that members in Group A see a profile where they fill in some custom fields (required) and on submission should be moved to Group B - can it be done?

Also is it possible that on this action occurring a mail be despatched to the site Admin to notify them?

Anyone know of the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ermm...

https://solspace.com/software/expressionengine/user/docs/edit/#f_group_id

Just make a hidden input for `group_id` on the form, and set it to Group B.

As for dispatching an email, write up a quick extension that is triggered by this hook:

https://solspace.com/software/expressionengine/user/docs/extension_hooks/#user_edit_end

And just use the email class:

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/email.html

to fire off an email. Boom.

**Edit**

As far as I can tell, MX Notify only has a trigger for Solspace User when a person is registered, not on profile edit. I would still go for writing a quick extension, it would take me less than 30 minutes.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html

Comment: Great, first part perfect thanks! Not sure how to do the extension though, is there an add-on? Would Notify MX work with User? Thanks!

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: User comes with these settings in the Control Panel, User Preferences: **Email(s) for Admin Notification on Profile Update** and **Admin Notify of Profile Update Email Message**. This should let you send emails on profile edit.